# get Array from Response in Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am making a curl request and the response in the in form like this:

```
data: [
    {
      data: {
         transaction: [
            [timestamp1, value1],
            [timestamp2, value2],
            [timestamp3, value3],
            [timestamp4, value4],
         ]
      }
    }
 ]
}
```

What I am doing

`curl $url | jq -r '.data[].data[].tansaction'`

which is giving output
`[ [key1: value1],[key2: value2], [key3: value], [key4: value] ]`

What I want to is to store the above result in an array so that I can iterate over it.
Final goal is to get each pair
key and value
and perform some operation over it

How can I do it in shell script?

Comment: It would help if you posted valid JSON. Did you mean `{key1: value1}` instead of `[key1: value1]`?

Comment: @glennjackman I think a correct JSON would have been `{"key1": "value1"}`.

Comment: Indeed, what @sonali put in his question does not validate as json, so jq will not work here.  Please post the result of the curl.

Comment: Hi, sorry. That was a wrong json. I have updated it. Its actually an array with two elements, with zero index being time and first index being c=value observed at that time. I hope it makes sense now

Comment: `jq -r '.data[].data[].tansaction | <iterate over it here>'`. Typically, you would `jq ... @tsv | while IFS=$'\t' read ....`